# I am using CKEditor for a Strapi Project and I want to change the default headings available

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, strapi

after following this guide: https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-change-the-wysiwyg-in-strapi I managed to install a WYSIWYG editor in the backend of a Strapi project. The only issue is that [by default it only allows me to use h1, h2, h3, p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVOxx.png). And the h1s turn into h2s by default. I would like to see if there is a way to override this and maybe have h1 - h6 available in my backend.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To add ckeditor on strapi (updated way) - https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/registering-a-field-in-admin.html#setup

You need to create custom build first by selecting plugins which you want and download the build
check here for the build  - https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

Then go to strapi plugins where you have WYSIWYG {path can be - /wysiwyg/admin/src/components/CKEditor}
paste the build folder content on the above given directory.

Now, to add custom headings - open CKEditor/index.js, You can do something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import AdvancedEditor from './ckeditor.js'; // custom plugin build 
import styled from 'styled-components';   



const contentTitleStyle = {
  name: 'h6',
  classes: ['content-title'], // this class will show in front-end
  styles: {
    'font-size': '26px',
    'color': '#000000',
    'font-style': 'italic',
    'line-height': '1.08',
    'margin-bottom': '15px',
  }
}
const configuration = {
  heading: {
    options: [
      { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph', view: contentParagraphStyle },
      { model: 'content', view: 'h6', title: 'Content Title', class: 'ck-heading_heading2', view: contentTitleStyle },
    ]
  },
  toolbar: [      // these plugins need to be add to reflect on strapi
    'heading',
    '|',
    'bold',
    'italic',
    'link',
    'blockQuote',
    'bulletedList',
    'numberedList',
    '|',
    'indent',
    'outdent',
    'alignment',
    '|',
    'mediaEmbed',
    '|',
    'image',
    'imageInsert',
    'imageCaption',
    'imageResize',
    '|',
    'undo',
    'redo',
    'fontSize',
    'fontColor',
    'fontFamily',
    'list',
  ],
};

const Editor = ({ onChange, name, value }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <CKEditor
        editor={AdvancedEditor}
        config={configuration}
        data={value}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          onChange({ target: { name, value: data } });
        }}
        onReady={(editor) => {
          if (value) {
            editor.setData(value);
          }
        }}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```